# trying to use each method to find divisible numbers and print them

Tags: ruby, each

I'm new to ruby and new to stack. I am trying to use the .each method on an array of numbers to see which numbers are divisible by 4, and 400. It is based on an exercises from Chris Pine's "Learn to Program" Ruby tutorial. In it you are supposed to find the leap years, then print them, from a range of years that the user inputs. I accomplished this using an if/else statement...but it seems to me this should be able to be done using the each method, or maybe the map method? Less code.

For example:

```
puts "Enter two years (to - from) to find out which years are leap years!" 

puts "Enter the first year.."

year1 = gets.chomp.to_i

puts "Now enter the second year"

year2 = gets.chomp.to_i

range = (year1..year2).to_a

puts "These are the leap years between those years:"

range.each do |year|

leaps = (year % 4 == 0 || year % 400 == 0)

end

puts leaps
```

this code may not be correct, but i have toyed with different ways of doing it (puts inside .each, defining variable outside, etc...) but nothing seems to work. Like I said, I accomplished it with an if/else...I just feel there may be a better way, and it's driving me nuts. Do i not understand the .each correctly? am i using the wrong method? can it be done at all using each/map/or collect???? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A detail: `gets.chomp.to_i` returns the same value as `gets.to_i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `puts` inside the `each` block too. Also, you can just divide by `4` and check if the remainder is `0`. No need of `400`

```
range.each do |year|
   puts year if year % 4 == 0;
end
```

The `puts year` will be executed only if the if condition is satisfied.

Comment: To find leap year divisible by four isn't good enough. Check: https://github.com/JikkuJose/exercism/tree/master/ruby/leap

Comment: Amit.... the instructions state a leap year is divisible by four, and years that are divisible by 100 are NOT leap years unless they are divisible by 400....so i figure i will need an if statement? is that where i am having the problem? can you not put an if statement in an .each block?

Comment: thank you Jikku for the link!!!  I am familiar with switch statements from javascript, but haven't tried them in ruby. Not that far yet. I love that it can be done with a switch, but im feeling/wondering if it can be done with an iterator once the range is in array - for less code :)